# How can i re-open remote files on startup in Aptana 3.3.1?

Tags: ftp, aptana, aptana3

In a previous Version of `Aptana` it was possible to re-open files from a remote connection (FTP) on startup. This feature is not available any more after some updates.

I wrote down this solution in March 2012:
**Window > Preferences > Aptana Studio > Remote > enable checkbox “Re-open previously opened remote files on startup”**

Unfortunately the checkbox was removed.
I'm currently using **Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.3.1.201212171919**

Would be great if the feature is still available.

Comment: I can confirm this behavior.  I just created issue in their jira (https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-7689).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The setting is now at the **Window > Preferences > Aptana Studio > Publishing** page.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Michael! That's what we've been looking for a quite a long time :-)